# How to place frame layout in bottom in the linear layout

Tags: android, layout

I am creating custom keyboard in Android. Keyboard view will be in frame layout. And I want to place this frame layout in bottom in the linear layout. Please give some idea for this.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing 2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing 3"/>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Custom Keyboard"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: Why not use a relative layout or a constraint layout ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to put a `View` with the attribute `android:layout_weight = "1"` between the last `TextView` and the `FrameLayout`

```
...

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Testing 3"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Custom Keyboard"/>

</FrameLayout>

...
```

Anyway, in this case I suggest using [Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) or, better, [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout)

Comment: Yes. I am also suggest to use Constraint layout. But the we need to use the existing architecture. That's why. You solution is working fine for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can try Constraint Layout for your view as:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SomeText 1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SomeText 2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SomeText 3"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_2"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="keyboard"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
</ScrollView>
```

u can use the parent as linear layout or scroll view.  just replace with scroll view.